# Get CDF from 2 variable PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have the following density function:

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{3x-y}{5} & \text{if } 1\leq x \leq 2, 1 \leq y \leq 3 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

I need to find the probability $P(X \leq 1.3, Y \leq 2.5 ) $. This becomes easy by obtaining the CDF but my question is how can I define the intervals having a PFD with 2 variables? My attempt was defining the integral with these boundaries:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{x} \int_{-\infty}^{y} \frac{3u-v}{5} dv du =  \int_{1}^{x} \int_{1}^{y} \frac{3u-v}{5} dv du$$ and then doing the integral but I don't know if my boundaries are correct. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

The proposed expression can be calculated through the formula:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X\leq 1.3, Y\leq 2.5) = \int_{1}^{1.3}\int_{1}^{2.5}\left(\frac{3x - y}{5}\right)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I get it! This is so intuitive, thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome ! I am glad I could help.